# Рандом ASCII C++

Tags: c++, случайные-числа, clion

Можно ли как то рандомить символы из ASCII C++? Если да то как? А то массивы символов не хочется вводить.

Comment: `(char)(rand() % 95 + 32)` ?

Answer (score 5):

Если только большие -

```
'A' + rand()%('Z'-'A'+1)
```

Если и большие, и маленькие - тут сложнее: между ними есть разрыв. Или их собрать в один массив, или

```
'A' + rand()%('Z'-'A'+1) + (rand()%2)*('a'-'A')
```

*"По-моему, так" (с) Пух*